# Mailchimp list created with API not available to API, but is in web admin view

Tags: php, mailchimp, php-curl, mailchimp-api-v3.0

I am using the MailChimp API and creating a list, and adding users to it

---

The process is as follows (cURL connections)

first I get the lists (no data sent with the GET request)

```
GET: https://{DC}.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists
```

then I query the list to see if the one I need is there with a search of the array returned and fetch the ID if it exists

If it does not exit I add a list (generating a ID in the return value)

```
POST: https://{DC}.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists
```

I then take that list ID (either existing or newly created one) and add my subscriber

```
POST: https://{DC}.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists/{listId}/members
```

All of this works

I can view the list in the MailChimp web admin and see the users, I can send emails and add / remove tags

I CANNOT see this list using the API though, when I run the first request to GET the lists again, the new list is not part of that returned result, so I end up making the list again

---

is there a delay before a created list is available to the API, is there a request I can make that will force it to update and make the newly created list available to me immediately via the API?

If I use the list ID directly in a cURL request it works, even if the API does not return it with a /lists/ GET request

Comment: How many lists do you have in your account? API docs for the list method say, _"`count`- The number of records to return. Default value is 10. Maximum value is 1000"_ - if you are really not passing any additional parameters with your list API call, then I guess this might simply be a pagination issue ...?

Comment: That could be an issue, I will check that, but if you put this as an answer I will mark it as accepted answer

Comment: -- tested, it does work, if you create an answer I will mark it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

API docs for the list method say,

> count: The number of records to return. Default value is 10. Maximum value is 1000

If you are not adding any additional parameters to your API call, you would only get the first 10 items.

So you'll have to specify `count` with your query, and if you have more than a 1,000 lists, you'd also need to use `offset`, to implement pagination through the records - https://mailchimp.com/developer/marketing/docs/methods-parameters/#pagination